# Is the Eucharist of non-Porvoo Lutheran church valid in the churches of Porvoo Communion?

Tags: communion, lutheranism, ecumenism

[Porvoo communion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porvoo_Communion) is the full Eucharistic communion of Lutheran churches of Northern Europe, but the Lutheran Church of Latvia is only observer in this communion. I understand that the Lutheran Church of Latvia does not recognize the Eucharist and Priesthood of Porvoo Communion (mainly because Porvoo communion admits woman to the priesthood and recognizes diversity in marriage), but what about the reverse order? **Does Porvoo communion recognizes the Eucharist and Priesthood of Latvian Church?** One can argue that the "stricter" character of the Latvia Church may make it "more sacred" and hence its sacraments should be recognized by the "less sacred" Churches (please, forgive me mentioning this somehow graphic and ironic argument). Or maybe Porvoo Communion is more open to the Christian practices and agrees to recognize the Eucharist even without reciprocal recognition?

I belong to the Church of Sweden and I have no possibility to attend the local Anglican Services (both Church of Sweden and Church of England belong to the Porvoo Communion) and there are no Church of Sweden Services but there are Latvian services. So - maybe I attend those Latvian services?

I know that this site is not for discussions about lifestyle and about righteousness, but my question is more judicial one - I am not arguing about superiority of one or other Church, I just wanted to know more about the practices and the documents of mentioned Churches concerning my question.

And just a note - I feel more comfortable with reformed Churches of Porvoo (than Catholic and more conservative Latvian Church), because Porvoo Churches are more open to the theological/rational research of their faith and this openness allows to adapt the true message of Jesus to the current state of the World. And yes - the current scientific and technological development has empowered people and the people should take advantage of this power and I feel that Reformed Churches are more willing to make practical works for the benefit of the society. Some unreformed Churches are not aware of this progress and are more willing to just pray and do nothing beyond what they have done forever. Reformed Churches are more energetic.